# How to check if array keys exist in multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

`var winArray = [
        [1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9],
        [1, 4, 7],
        [2, 5, 8],
        [3, 6, 9],
        [1, 5, 9],
        [7, 5, 3]
    ];`

And another array like this:
`var Xarray = [1,2,3]`

How can I check that the first array's index 0 contains my second array? Another issue is that the value order should not be regarded during the compression

Comment: @BenjaminTrent: Not really. That won't work for arrays, as they won't be `==` to each other (unless they point to the same instance, which is unlikely).

Comment: Compare winArray[0][0] to Xarray[0], winArray[0][1] to Xarray[1] and winArray[0][2] to Xarray[2].  If they are all equal, they are the same.

Comment: @Coda17 That's not the solution. I don't always know the value of XArray and index of winArray...

Comment: Check this SO question and loop through the first deminsion of winArray: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/comparing-two-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: @GeorgeSharvadze You specifically said "the first array's index 0 contains my second array" which is what I answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the arrays to new arrays, so that you can sort them, then compare each item in the arrays:

```
var a1 = winArray[0].slice(0);
var a2 = Xarray.slice(0);

var equal = a1.length == a2.length;
if (equal) {
    a1.sort();
    a2.sort();
    for (var i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
        if (a1[i] != a2[i]) {
            equal = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/oa11qc4r/

---

If you mean that you want to search the array for a match, and not only compare the array at index 0, you would loop through the array and compare each array:

```
var a1 = Xarray.slice(0);
a1.sort();

var equal = false;
for (var j = 0; !equal && j < winArray.length; j++) {
    var a2 = winArray[j].slice(0);

    equal = a1.length == a2.length;
    var index = j;
    if (equal) {
        a2.sort();
        for (var i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
            if (a1[i] != a2[i]) {
                equal = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/oa11qc4r/1/

Comment: That's close. What if I don't know the index of the winArray? Your code will only work if the Xarray = winArray[0]

Comment: @GeorgeSharvadze: I figured that you might mean that, even if you specifically asked for how to check the array at index 0. I already added code for that.

Answer (score 0):

Might give this a shot. The function will return the index of the 'child array' if its found in the main data array. If its not found -1 will be returned.

```
var winArray = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [3, 6, 9],
    [1, 5, 9],
    [7, 5, 3]
];

var Xarray = [1,2,3];

function indexOfPredicate(data, value, predicate) {
  if (typeof(predicate) !== 'function') {
    throw "Predicate must be a function"
  }

  for(var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
    if (predicate(data[x], value)) {
        return x
    }
  }

  return -1;
}

function indexOfMulti(data, value) {
  return indexOfPredicate(data, value, function(a, b) {
    if (a.length !== b.length) {
      return false;
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      if (a[i] !== b[i]) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
  })
}

var index = indexOfMulti(winArray, Xarray);
var contains = index > -1;

console.log(index);
console.log(contains);
```